# Ler arquivo contatos agenda iPhone usando Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Como faço para ler a lista de contatos da agenda telefônica do iPhone utilizando o Xamarin?

Preciso ler a lista de contatos da agenda do iPhone. Não sei como fazer e não encontrei material em português sobre o assunto. Alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão?

Comment: Não considero duplicada, são coisas distintas e o proposto na outra pergunta nem é possível de se fazer.

Comment: A qualidade está muito baixa. Seria bom mudar o título que está só com as keywords. Se a gente sinalizar, qualquer moderador recebe o aviso ou só o Gabe?

Comment: @VictorHugo Tem coisas que podemos fazer sem moderador: editar, votar contra, votar para fechar (ou qualquer combinação das três). Eu votei para fechar (como ampla demais). O que o Gabe poderia fazer seria fechar imediatamente ou excluir.

Comment: Coloquei esta pergunta (e as irmãs dela) em discussão no meta: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/521/tres-perguntas-amplas-demais-o-que-fazer

Comment: Gente, a notificação de que há uma resposta na pergunta de [logs de chamadas no iPhone](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2208/como-faco-para-ler-o-log-das-chamadas-recebidas-e-efetuadas-no-iphone-utilizando) não procede. São coisas diferentes. A resposta em questão está correta, mas a resposta para esta pergunta é a que está abaixo. Há outras formas de fazer isso também. De qualquer forma não deveria estar marcada como duplicada da outra. Uma é sobre registro do histórico de chamadas outra é sobre conseguir acesso à lista de contatos da agenda do usuário no iPhone.

Comment: Gente, alguém mais pode votar para reabrir esta questão para podermos deixar corrigida a questão já que vários usuários não a consideram duplicada?

Answer (score 9):

#### 1 - Instancie um ABAddressBook.

```js
using(var addressBook = new ABAddressBook ()){ … }
```

#### 2 - Chame GetPeopleWithName, passando o nome do contato a pesquisar. Esse método retorna um array de objetos ABPerson.

```js
var people = addressBook.GetPeopleWithName ("John Doe");
people.ToList ().ForEach (
       p => Console.WriteLine ("{0} {1} - ", p.FirstName, p.LastName));
```

Juntamente com GetPeopleWithName, ABAddressBook temos o método GetPeople. Usando Linq, o resultado pode ser filtrado baseado em algum criério, como mostrado:

```js
var people = addressBook.GetPeople ();
people.ToList ().FindAll (p => p.LastName == "Smith").ForEach (
       p => Console.WriteLine ("{0} {1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName));
```

---

Fonte: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/contacts/